# Given $f= x^2$ what does $T_f$ look like?

Tags: general-topology

Let $T$ denote the metric induced topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Furthermore, let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, \ f(x) = x^2$. How does the topology $T_f$ (the topology on $\mathbb{R}$ that is induced by f to the topological space $(\mathbb{R},T))$ look like?

Per definition $T_f = \{f^{-1}(U) : U \text{ open } \subset \mathbb{R}\} = \{(-b,-a) \cup (a,b) : 0 \leq a < b \}$. So $T_f$ is the union of two open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ where the coordinates are equal up to the sign?

Comment: $0 \leq a < b\iff0\geq{-a}>-b$

Comment: You mean I could skip the $: 0 \leq a<b$? @MichaelMcGovern

Comment: @Obla12 he means you should have written $(-b,-a)$

Comment: Not every open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is an open interval.

Comment: ohh misstypo. @Omnomnomnom

Comment: Plus, $f^{-1}((-1, 1)) = (-1, 1)$ so $(-1, 1)$ is also open in $T_f$.

Comment: No, $U$ could also be a union and/or intersection of open intervals. @DanielSchepler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two important observations:

- $\{U \cap [0,\infty) : U \in T_f\} = \{U \cap [0,\infty) : U \in T\}$
- For every $U \in T_f$: $x \in U \implies -x \in U$

All together, the sets in $T_f$ are all of the form $U \cup -U$ for some $U \in T$ (where $-U = \{-x: x \in U\}$).

Comment: Am I missing something, or is the first line saying both same things right and left of the $=$ sign?

Comment: @Olba12 Fixed it now!  Sorry